# C++ error: '#'indirect_ref' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>' is not a template

Tags: c++, template, c++17

Para poder formular la pregunta correctamente empezaré explicando el contexto y después pasaré a la pregunta.

### El contexto: Metafunciones perezosas

Empecé [este proyecto](https://github.com/Hectarea1996) para comprobar si podía trasladar alguna de las funcionalidades de Haskell a los templates de C++. El resultado principal fue crear la clase Currying, que curryfica "metafunciones perezosas".

**1. ¿Qué es una "metafunción perezosa"?**

Simplemente es una metafunción que recibe los parámetros de forma tardía.

```
//Metafuncion
template<int arg1, int arg2>  
struct Suma{
    static constexpr int value = arg1+arg2;
}

//Metafuncion perezosa
struct SumaPerezosa{
    template<int arg1, int arg2>
    static constexpr int value = arg1+arg2;
}

int main(){
    int s1 = Suma<3,4>::value;
    int s2 = SumaPerezosa::value<3,4>;
}
```

**2. ¿Como curryficar las metafunciones perezosas?**

Usamos la clase Currying de la [librería](https://github.com/Hectarea1996) como se muestra a continuación:

```
struct Suma : Currying<Suma,int(int,int)>{ // <-- Añadimos esto aquí, indicando el tipo de la metafuncion perezosa.
    template<int arg1,int arg2>
    static constexpr int value = arg1+arg2;
}

//Podemos definir nuevas metafunciones perezosas de esta forma
using Sucesor = Suma::let<1>;

int main(){
    int s1 = Sucesor::let<5>; // <-- Me devuelve un 6.
}
```

Este es un ejemplo sencillo, pero se pueden curryficar metafunciones perezosas que reciban cualquier parametro non-type (excepto lvalues, que da un error origen de esta pregunta), o cualquier parametro type (con mecanismos de restricción de tipos, está explicado en el [github de la libreria](https://github.com/Hectarea1996)).

### La pregunta

Aunque no es estrictamente necesario, me gustaría que la librería pudiese aceptar cualquier parámetro non-type, incluyendo referencias (lvalue), pero en la clase Currying recibo el error que da nombre a la pregunta. A continuación presentaré una situación en la que se produce dicho error:

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente metafunción perezosa:

```
struct LazyId{
    template<int& x>
    static constexpr int& value = x;
}
```

Ahora tengo que usar una metafunción (no perezosa) que recibe una metafunción perezosa y su argumento:

```
template<class F, int& Arg>
struct Indirect{
    static constexpr int& value = F::template value<Arg>;
}
```

Esto también compila, excepto si lo usamos:

```
int unEntero = 3;

int main(){
    std::cout << Indirect<LazyId,unEntero>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Esto no compila y da el siguiente error:

```
template<class F, int& Arg>
struct Indirect{
    static constexpr int& value = F::template value<Arg>;  // <-- Error aqui
}

'#'indirect_ref' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>' is not a template [-fpermissive]
```

El error parece indicar que es algo que no está soportado por el compilador, cuando para cualquier otro parámetro non-type sí funciona.
¿Qué está ocurriendo?
¿Es un error de C++ o del compilador (MINGW)?
¿Esto está contemplado en el Standard de C++?

Comment: POR FIN una pregunta interesante sobre plantillas. <3

Comment: Gracias :D, si no se entiende bien la pregunta avisadme y la edito, pondré algún ejemplo más.

Comment: Opino lo mismo que  @eferion. Si lo que intentas hacer es <abr title="Template Meta Programming">TMP</abr> ``Meta Programación de Plantillas`` estás yendo por el camino equivocado por lo ya indicado por  @eferion. Por otro lado, el error en la plantilla LazyIndirect es porque estas tratando de usar el parámetro de _F_  como plantilla y _F_ está referenciando a un __tipo__.

Comment: Acabo de reformular la pregunta añadiendo el contexto donde se produce y con algún ejemplo de por qué uso los template de esa forma no convencional. Espero que esto ayude a entender mejor la pregunta. :D

Answer (score 2):

No termino de entender la necesidad de este tipo de usos... ¿cual es el objetivo final?

Quiero decir, ¿por qué es necesario hacerlo así? Las plantillas se evalúan en tiempo de compilación, usar una referencia atenta contra el propio principio de la plantilla... ya que el valor nunca será conocido en tiempo de compilación por mucho que C++17 acepte el primer uso

Por ejemplo, la gracia de `constexpr` es obligar al compilador a aceptar un valor en tiempo de compilación y usarlo en lugar de la correspondiente variable... lo cual permite aplicar ciertas optimizaciones sobre el código final.... el problema aquí es que al usar una referencia, el valor **nunca** va a ser conocido, luego las posibles ventajas asociadas a `constexpr` se pierden irremediablemente.

Dado que el compilador no podrá optimizar nada... no veo la necesidad de aplicar este tipo de técnicas. Para este tipo de usos ya están los parámetros de las funciones... resultando un código más limpio y legible.

Quizás un ejemplo de uso podría ayudar a entender la necesidad de este tipo de prácticas o bien a ofrecer un mecanismo más limpio y funcional

Comment: Gracias por responder @eferion. Esa forma de usar los template la necesito para la libreria que estoy creando. La idea principal es que con esa forma nos acercamos mas a la programacion funcional pura, ya que podenos usar un struct como funcion, de forma que podemos aceptar como parametros otros struct como si fuesen funciones. Tengo pensado reformular la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis Tengo la impresión de que o te estás confundiendo de lenguaje o de paradigma... la programación funcional no dice nada acerca de que las estructuras de datos tengan que ser funciones... la programación funcional habla de estructuras de datos planas y toda la lógica basada en funciones... ese paradigma dista mucho de lo que comentas

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, simplemente son conceptos que he creado yo para mi libreria, sólo eso. Mi librería intenta simular Haskell con los templates. ¿El por qué? Me apetecía. Una de las cosas que he conseguido es una metafuncion que curryfica las metafunciones. Y solo puedo hacerlo si uso los template de esa forma.

Comment: La libreria que comento es esta https://github.com/Hectarea1996/Pure-Functional-Template-Language.git

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis prácticamente todos los lenguajes sirven para cualquier cosa... pero la forma de alcanzar el objetivo depende del lenguaje utilizado. Yo, por ejemplo, me hice una librería IOC para controlar el ciclo de vida de los objetos... y avancé bastante hasta que me topé con los límites del lenguaje... en este caso cómo se gestionan las funciones virtuales y la herencia. La conclusión final es que para usar IOC en condiciones, C++ no es una opción salvo que empieces a imponer muchas restricciones al propio lenguaje.

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis dicho esto, intentar emular otro lenguaje esá bien... como proyecto de pruebas. Hay que ser conscientes que lenguajes diferentes se comportan de formas distintas y que es posible que no se pueda lograr una emulación completa... o que el resultado no pueda salir del entorno de investigación por ser poco usable... me da la impresión de que es en el punto en el que tu te encuentras

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis Piensa que ningún programador senior de C++ se va a poner a programar C++ como si fuese Haskell... ni python ni JS. Simplemente porque las reglas que permiten que el código que escribes en C++ sea legible, seguro y mantenible no son compatibles con estos otros lenguajes

Comment: Tampoco buscaba eso, no creo que lo use yo tampoco. Si lo he usado es por puro divertimento. Creo que la respuesta que mas buscaba era que es un limite del lenguaje o simplemente que es algo que no esta soportado. Con eso me basta. No pretendia cambiar la forma de usar C++ ni nada parecido.

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis Bueno, en ese caso, si reformulas la pregunta podremos echarle un ojo :)